How to setup slds-grid for screens with less than 480px
My slds-grid gets broken when pixels of the screen gets less than 480px, as per salesforce documentation, there is not option available for screens less than 480px to set grid for. But Mobile screens are always less than 480px.
<div class="slds-wrap slds-grid">
<aura:iteration items="{!v.currentWO.fieldNameValueList}" var="workOrder">
<aura:if isTrue="{!or(workOrder.fieldName == 'Priority' , workOrder.fieldName == 'Product Type')}">
<div class="slds-small-size_1-of-3 slds-medium-size_1-of-4">
<div class="slds-truncate right-align-fields">
    {!workOrder.fieldValue}</div>
</div>
</aura:if> 
<aura:if isTrue="{!or(workOrder.fieldName == 'Account' , workOrder.fieldName == 'Case #')}">
 <div class="slds-small-size_2-of-3 slds-medium-size_1-of-4">
 <div class="slds-small-size_1-of-3">
 <div class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak workorder-subdetails">{!workOrder.fieldName}:</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slds-small-size_2-of-3">
  <div class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate workorder-subdetails">
      {!workOrder.fieldValue}</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </aura:if>
  </aura:iteration>
 </div>

This is working fine for 480px+:

but not working for less than 480px screens:

Anyone please guide.
